Why does my powershell runspace not increase performance?
so basically, i am looking at doing a comparison between accounts we have in Active Directory and a csv which lists all active accounts (~15000 lines). This process would be ran weekly.
The issue that I am coming across is that runspaces do not seem to increase performance of the script after a certain point; i.e., before using multiple runspaces, the script took about 28-30 minutes to gather and cross reference data but after incorporating 2 runspaces, that dropped down to ~18 minutes.
So i thought - thats great, increase available runspaces and should see multiplicative decrease in time to process. Unfortunately, that isnt what happened, and as the script stands, I have increased the number of runspaces to 8, but only seen maybe 10 second performance increase.
Basically, I am getting the same performance out of 8 runspaces as I am getting out of 2 runspaces.
The server this runs on has 4 sockets, 2 cores per socket. Am i stupid? Missing something obvious? Or do i need to research and get a better handle on expected gains from multiple runspaces?
And yes, I know I am not using the term delta list accurately; changed process halfway through and never went back to correct var names :)
#Declarations
$DeltaListInactive = @() #these accounts exist in AD within the account OU, but are not actively enrolled accounts
$DeltaListActiveNotFound = @() #these accounts exist only in the CSV import - accounts have not been created or otherwise do not exist in AD, no actions will be processed against these accounts
$DeltaListActive = [System.Collections.Queue]::Synchronized([System.Collections.Queue]::new()) #these accounts exist in the CSV Sheet, and in AD. Actively enrolled and may require accounts changes based on CSV Sheet
$CSVImport= [System.Collections.Queue]::Synchronized($SynImport)


#region Information Gathering
##Build Comparison/Delta list
$ImportComparison = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $CSVImport.UserID -DifferenceObject $ADImport.sAMAccountName -IncludeEqual
foreach($result in $ImportComparison)
{
    if($result.SideIndicator -eq '=>') #these accounts are found in AD but do not exist in the CSV import; these accounts will be disabled and moved to the corresponding disabled account OU; logging for this process WILL NOT occur here
    {
        $DeltaListInactive += $result.InputObject
    }

    if($result.SideIndicator -eq '<=') #these accounts exist in the CSV import, but do not exist in AD; these accounts will not be processed in any way; logging for this process WILL occur here
    {
        $DeltaListActiveNotFound += $result.InputObject
        $ActiveNotFoundLog += "`r`n$((Get-Date).ToString("hh:mm:ss")) // Account --> $($result.InputObject) <-- not found in Active Directory. Account will not be processed."
    }
    
    if($result.SideIndicator -eq '==') #these accounts are found in AD and the CSV import; these accounts will be checked for any pending changes and have them applied; logging for this process WILL NOT occur here
    {
       $DeltaListActive.Enqueue($result.InputObject)
    }
}

$ActiveNotFoundLog | Out-File -FilePath $LogLocation\$ActiveNotFoundLogFilename -Force -WhatIf:$false

$QueueCount = $DeltaListActive.Count

$ScriptBlock = {
    param (
        $DeltaListActive,
        $CSVImport
    )
    while( $DeltaListActive.Count -gt 0 ) {
        $Activeaccount = $DeltaListActive.Dequeue()

        #Gather account information from AD
        $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $Activeaccount -Properties distinguishedName,memberof,surname,givenname,telephonenumber,enabled,employeeid,office
    
        #declare change flags
        [int]$ChangesRequired = 0
        [bool]$ChangeStatus = $false
        [bool]$ChangeOU = $false
        [bool]$ChangeBuilding = $false
        [bool]$ChangeGradYear = $false
        [bool]$ChangeaccountID = $false
        [bool]$ChangeGroups = $false

        $CurrentADInfo = $null
        $CurrentADInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
            AccountName = $ADUser.SamAccountName
            Enabled = $ADUser.Enabled
            OrgUnit = ($ADUser.DistinguishedName.Split(",") | Where-Object {-Not $_.StartsWith("CN=")}) -join ","
            Building = $ADUser.Office
            GradYear = $ADUser.telephonenumber
            accountID = $ADUser.EmployeeID
            Groups = ($ADUser.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | Select-Object Name).Name
        }

        $CSVUser = $CSVImport | Where-Object UserID -eq $Activeaccount
        $NewCSVInfo = $null
        $NewCSVInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
            AccountName = $CSVUser.UserID
            Enabled = "True"
            OrgUnit = "OU=20$($CSVUser.'Year'),OU=accounts,OU=domain,DC=domain,DC=local"
            Building = $CSVUser.'Building Number'

            GradYear = "20$($CSVUser.'Year')"
            accountID = $CSVUser.accountID
            Groups = @("$($CSVUser.'Building Number')-accounts","accounts-Year')","Internet-All-accounts")
        }

        #Check for necessary changes and pass to action hash

        #if account disabled, then set required status change flag to true
        if(-not $CurrentADInfo.Enabled)
        {
            $ChangeStatus = $true
            $ChangesRequired++
        }

        #if incorrect OU, then set change GradYear flag
        if($CurrentADInfo.OrgUnit -ne $NewCSVInfo.OrgUnit)
        {
            $ChangeOU = $true
            $ChangesRequired++
        }

        #if incorrect building, then set change building flag
        if($CurrentADInfo.Building -ne $NewCSVInfo.Building)
        {
            $ChangeBuilding = $true
            $ChangesRequired++
        }

        #if incorrect Gradyear, then set change gradyear flag
        if($CurrentADInfo.GradYear -ne $NewCSVInfo.GradYear)
        {
            $ChangeGradYear = $true
            $ChangesRequired++
        }

        #if incorrect accountid, then set change accountid flag
        if($CurrentADInfo.accountID -ne $NewCSVInfo.accountID)
        {
            $ChangeaccountID = $true
            $ChangesRequired++
        }

        #if incorrect groups, then set change groups flag
        $CorrectGroupCount = 0
        foreach($group in $NewCSVInfo.Groups)
        {
            if($CurrentADInfo.Groups -match $group)
            {
                $CorrectGroupCount++
            }
        }

        if($CorrectGroupCount -ne $NewCSVInfo.Groups.Count)
        {
            $ChangeGroups = $true
            $ChangesRequired++
        }

        $CurrentUserActions = [PSCustomObject]@{
            account_Username = $ADUser.SamAccountName
            Distinguished_Name = $ADUser.DistinguishedName
            Changes_Required = $ChangesRequired
            Status_Change_Required = $ChangeStatus
            OU_Change_Required = $ChangeOU
            Building_Change_Required = $ChangeBuilding
            GradYear_Change_Required = $ChangeGradYear
            accountID_Change_Required = $ChangeaccountID
            Group_Change_Required = $ChangeGroups
            OLD_ENABLED = $CurrentADInfo.Enabled
            NEW_ENABLED = $NewCSVInfo.Enabled
            OLD_OU = $CurrentADInfo.OrgUnit
            NEW_OU = $NewCSVInfo.OrgUnit
            OLD_BUILDING = $CurrentADInfo.Building
            NEW_BUILDING = $NewCSVInfo.Building
            OLD_GRADYEAR = $CurrentADInfo.GradYear
            NEW_GRADYEAR = $NewCSVInfo.GradYear
            OLD_accountID = $CurrentADInfo.accountID
            NEW_accountID = $NewCSVInfo.accountID
            OLD_GROUPS = $CurrentADInfo.Groups -join ','
            NEW_GROUPS = $NewCSVInfo.Groups -join ','
        }
        if($ChangesRequired -gt 0)
        {
            $CurrentUserActions
        }
    }
    
}

$Inputs = New-Object 'System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[PSObject]'
$ActiveActionHash = New-Object 'System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[PSObject]'

$runspace_start = Get-Date
Write-Host "Starting runspaces... $($runspace_start.ToString("hh:mm:ss"))"

$Instances = @()
(1..8) | ForEach-Object { # (1..X) signifies the number of runspaces to create in order to process these requests
    $Instance = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($ScriptBlock).AddParameter('DeltaListActive', $DeltaListActive).AddParameter('CSVImport',$CSVImport)
    $Instances += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Instance = $Instance
        State = $Instance.BeginInvoke($Inputs,$ActiveActionHash)
    }
}

while ( $Instances.State.IsCompleted -contains $False) {
    # Report the accounts left in the queue
    $time_spent = [Timespan]::FromMilliseconds(((Get-Date) - $runspace_start).TotalMilliseconds)
    Write-Progress -Activity "Gathering account information..." -Status "account(s) Remaining: $($DeltaListActive.Count)/$($QueueCount)... $($time_spent.Hours)h $($time_spent.Minutes)m $($time_spent.Seconds)s" -PercentComplete (($DeltaListActive.count/$QueueCount)*100)
    
}


Running Get-ADUser once per user for 15,000 users is going to be slow - you might be better off reading them all into an array in a single call with a filter to target the appropriate OU before you spin up the runspaces, and then search the array in-memory for the $Activeaccount inside the runspaces. Also threads don’t scale linearly - more threads means more synchronisation overhead - only one can Dequeue() at a time for example so there will still be natural bottlenecks…

You could try splitting $DeltaListActive into N smaller arrays and passing a different one to each runspace so they don’t need to synchronise, or maybe just $DeltaListActive | foreach-object -Parallel instead of runspaces. You’ll test to test and measure to see which is faster…

What is $adimport?

$adimport is just a list generated using Get-Aduser and targetting user OUs.

@mclayton in my testing calling get-aduser in the loop is way faster than pulling from an array of 20,000 accounts. I do have an array declared with all users, but it is used for separate purpose. Did some more testing, and it appears my bottleneck is how I am pulling from the CSV w/ 15k lines using Where-Object... when that portion of the process is removed, times are dropped by almost 80%

@mclayton also - dealing w/ powershell v5 on the server -parallel isnt an option unfortunately; that was my first thought as well

If you explained what the comparison between CSV and AD was about and give examples this would be easier to answer. If pulling users from AD was the slow part you could create dynamic LDAPFilters to pull all users in the CSV at once, this doesnt require any multithreading.

Consider converting $CSVImport into a Hashtable so you can get rid of the slow Where-Object in your code

@Theo I agree - using the Where-Object seems to be the big slow-down with the whole process; just did some testing and was able to majorly cut down times using a hashtable.
Issue now is that outputs from runspace seem to be incomplete for some reason... mostly when capturing AD groups... i.e., person belongs to 4 groups, but the runspace instance is only outputting 2 groups. Specifically this line in the $CurrentADInfo object: Groups = ($ADUser.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | Select-Object Name).Name

Its strange - because if I run the script block by itself against a user; it functions perfectly and is 100% accurate. But pumping that same scriptblock through the runspace it starts reporting groups inaccurately... Not sure how to break into the runspaces and debug what is happening in there - or return any potential errors from runspace

You could shorten that code to get the group names like this Groups = ($ADUser.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup).Name (no need for Select-Object Name), but I doubt if that helps with the incomplete listing.. Maybe you need to specify the -Server and/or -SearchBase parameters on the Get-ADGroup command?
